# How can condition only the columns of the two-dimensional array in if statements?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, columnsorting, dimensional

No matter how hard I look, there is no way through Java, so I am inquiring directly. Please let me know if it's impossible or what to do if possible. please...

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426909/get-columns-from-two-dimensional-array-in-java

Comment: ooooooooooh thank you!!!

Comment: not perfect answer, but That well do!