# How to set a specific value of a 2D arrayList equals to a 2D array value?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void fillSolvingOrder(List<List<String>>  
                  theOrderScript,List<List<String>> theOrder) {
    String[][] convert = new String[theOrderScript.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < theOrderScript.size(); i++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < theOrderScript.get(0).size(); x++){
            convert[i][x]= theOrderScript.get(i).get(x);
            System.out.println(convert[i][x]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your question needs a lot of work for us to know exactly what the problem is and what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to ask, but this seems like what you want:
[How to get a column from a 2D java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111998/how-to-get-a-column-from-a-2d-java-array)

In short, you can do this, if it's what you want to do:

```
String[][] names = new String[3][3];
names[0][0] = "JimBob";
names[0][1] = "Spongebob";
names[0][2] = "BillyBob";
String[] getNames = [names[0][0], names[0][1], names[0][2]];
ArrayList<List<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<<List<String>>(new List<String>(getNames));
```

Please provide some more context if this isn't what you're looking for, but if it is, then cool

Comment: Please don't downvote my comment when your question isn't clear. I was trying to help with what I thought you were asking.

Comment: Also, why do you need to do the conversion in the first place? You could just have a `String[][]` that contains your information, and you can do just about everything that you can do with an array with a `String[][]`, using different methods.